# Go fails to download deps from github

Tags: git, go

I work in Ubuntu that runs as WSL.
When I run `go get...` or `go mod tidy` I get an error:

```
server response:
not found: github.com/...@v0.0.0-20221103104148-6de67823a269: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/1be23be97dc50217968ea7f116bfef7f3861715200675bd9dd7563645ba58690: exit status 128:
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
        Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
        If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

What I already did:

1. updated git config file with `insteadOf`. Now config is :

```bash
$ git config --list
user.name=user-name
user.email=user@gmail.com
url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadof=https://github.com/
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
```

2. I added public key to GitHub. As far as I'm able to clone repo I guess there are no authentication issues.

My Go envs are:

```bash
$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/usr/local/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/home/user/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/user/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/usr/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/user/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.19.3"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/test/test-wsl/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build1637247891=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: Maybe it's a go thing, but it seems very unusual to have `-g -O2` in LDFLAGS of any kind.  It's almost certainly not the source of your current issue, but it looks weird.

Comment: that's another interesting issue . But hell, is there any idea about dependencies?